# MySQL specific database configuration file

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration

In MySQL's configuration file I've globally disabled autocommit as so.

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
```

I need to turn MySQL's autocommit on for a specific Ruby on Rails database though. It could be for the user or the database itself (doesn't matter). Thinking it would look something like this.

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
execute_sql="Custom SQL to set autocommit for a database"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say

- you are using MySQL in Linux
- datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`

You could use the [**init-file**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) option

You could just create an init file called `/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql`

Put the customer SQL in `/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql`

You could then try one of two things

## Try #1

Add this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
```

then run

```
service mysql restart
```

## Try #2

Directly run this

```
service mysql restart --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

That was a global setting of init code. If your session has to enable autocommit, then just run

```
SET autocommit=0
```

in the session or put `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` in the init-file option file. This may still not produce the effect you want since everything goes back to default settings upon connection termination.

## UPDATE 2013-02-28 15:40 EST

If you are looking for a startup option for my.cnf to affect the client, try this:

```
[client]
autocommit=0
```

or

```
[mysql]
autocommit=0
```

Perhaps try adding another `my.cnf` in the Linux home directory with these options

For more information, see the [MySQL Options File Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)

Comment: I really like the abstraction into a separate file here.

Comment: Does a similar inline command exist such as init-command="mysql here". I saw that on a few StackOverflow pages, but it throws an error.

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: I'm able to get things loading from the file, but unable to toggle autocommit=0 for a specific user or database.